ASP.NET Core 8 Web API : certificate authentication is not working
I have a library I created originally in .NET 6. I recently performed an in-place upgrade to .NET 8. Now, the library code never executes.
Here is the code for the AuthenticationService class (implements an interface, IAuthenticationService, that has a stub for the IsValidClientCertificate method -- used in dependency injection):
using System.Configuration;
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Services.Interfaces;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Corp.Lib.Logging;

namespace Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Services
{
    public class AuthenticationService : IAuthenticationService
    {
        private readonly ClientCertificateSettings _ClientCertificateSettings;

        public AuthenticationService(IOptions<ClientCertificateSettings> options)
        {
            _ClientCertificateSettings = options.Value;
        }

        public bool IsValidClientCertificate(X509Certificate2 clientCertificate)
        {
            if (clientCertificate == null!)
            {
                var error = new ConfigurationErrorsException("Missing certificate or certificate not sent by client.");

                Logger.Log.Error(error, "Certificate validation failed. Missing certificate or certificate not sent by client.");

                throw error;
            }

            if (_ClientCertificateSettings == null! || _ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates == null! || !_ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates.ToList().Any())
            {
                var error = new ConfigurationErrorsException("Certificate configuration missing. Check AppSettings.");

                Logger.Log.Error(error, "Certificate validation failed. Certificate configuration missing. Check AppSettings.");

                throw error;
            }

            if (_ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates.Any(cert => string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert.Subject)))
            {
                var error = new ConfigurationErrorsException("Certificate configuration missing Subject. Check AppSettings.");

                Logger.Log.Error(error, "Certificate validation failed. Certificate configuration missing Subject. Check AppSettings.");

                throw error;
            }

            if (_ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates.Any(cert => string.IsNullOrEmpty(cert.Issuer)))
            {
                var error = new ConfigurationErrorsException("Certificate configuration missing Subject. Check AppSettings.");

                Logger.Log.Error(error, "Certificate validation failed. Certificate configuration missing Issuer. Check AppSettings.");

                throw error;
            }

            // 1. Check time validity of certificate.
            if (DateTime.Compare(DateTime.UtcNow, clientCertificate.NotBefore) < 0 || DateTime.Compare(DateTime.UtcNow, clientCertificate.NotAfter) > 0)
            {
                Logger.Log.Warning($"Certificate with thumbprint {clientCertificate.Thumbprint} is expired.");

                return false;
            }

            // 2. Check subject name of certificate.
            var foundSubject = false;

            var certSubjectData = clientCertificate.Subject.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            if (certSubjectData.Any(certSubject => _ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates.Any(cert => cert.Subject.Equals(certSubject.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))))
            {
                foundSubject = true;
            }

            if (!foundSubject)
            {
                Logger.Log.Warning($"Certificate with thumbprint {clientCertificate.Thumbprint} does not have a matching Subject.");

                return false;
            }

            // 3. Check issuer name of certificate.
            var certIssuerData = clientCertificate.Issuer.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            var foundIssuer = certIssuerData.Any(issuerData => _ClientCertificateSettings.AllowedCertificates.Any(cert => cert.Issuer.Equals(issuerData.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));

            if (!foundIssuer)
            {
                Logger.Log.Warning($"Certificate with thumbprint {clientCertificate.Thumbprint} does not have a matching Issuer.");

                return false;
            }

            // Check if the Certificate exists in the personal cert store.
            if (_ClientCertificateSettings.CheckThumbprintInCertStore)
            {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

                try
                {
                    store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                    var certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, clientCertificate.Thumbprint, true);

                    if (certs.Count == 0)
                    {
                        Logger.Log.Warning("Invalid client certificate. The thumbprint does not match with a certificate in the certificate store. {@clientCertificate}", clientCertificate);

                        return false;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Logger.Log.Error(ex, "An exception occurred searching for the client certificate in the certificate store. {@clientCertificate}", clientCertificate);

                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    store.Close();

                    store.Dispose();
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}

Here is the code for the ServiceCollectionExtension static extension class:
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Configuration;
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Services;
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Services.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Certificate;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Extensions
{
    public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
    {
        public static void AddCertificateAuthenticationService(this WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure<ClientCertificateSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection("ClientCertificateSettings"));

            // Require a certificate from any client sending a request.
            builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(kestrel =>
            {
                kestrel.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(defaults =>
                {
                    defaults.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.RequireCertificate;
                });
            });

            builder.Services.AddCertificateForwarding(options =>
            {
                options.CertificateHeader = "ssl-client-cert";

                options.HeaderConverter = (headerValue) =>
                {
                    X509Certificate2? clientCertificate = null;

                    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(headerValue))
                    {
                        clientCertificate = X509Certificate2.CreateFromPem(WebUtility.UrlDecode(headerValue));
                    }

                    return clientCertificate!;
                };
            });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IAuthenticationService, AuthenticationService>();

            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate(options =>
            {
                options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.Chained;

                options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
                {
                    OnCertificateValidated = context =>
                    {
                        var validationService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IAuthenticationService>();

                        if (validationService.IsValidClientCertificate(context.ClientCertificate))
                        {
                            var claims = new[]
                            {
                                new Claim(
                                    ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier,
                                    context.ClientCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false),
                                    ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                    context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                                new Claim(
                                    ClaimTypes.Name,
                                    context.ClientCertificate.GetNameInfo(X509NameType.SimpleName, false),
                                    ClaimValueTypes.String,
                                    context.Options.ClaimsIssuer)
                            };

                            context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));

                            context.Success();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Fail("Invalid certificate.");
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

            builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
        }

        public static void UseCertificateAuthenticationService(this WebApplication app)
        {
            app.UseCertificateForwarding();
            
            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();
        }
    }
}

Finally, here is the Program.cs for the Web API project referencing the certificate authentication library (the logging is required in my project, but not included here -- please comment out references):
using Corp.Lib.CertificateAuthentication.Extensions;
using Corp.Lib.Logging.Extensions;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.AddLogging(false);
builder.AddCertificateAuthenticationService();

builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseLogging(false);
app.UseCertificateAuthenticationService();

app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI();

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

The implementation I included in the previous step was basically verbatim of Microsoft Learn's Prescribed Implementation found here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth?view=aspnetcore-8.0). I cannot even get the browser to prompt me for the certificate anymore. When it does in a UAT scenario with IIS as the web server, it prompts me for a certificate, but it ignores the AuthenticationService's IsValidClientCertificate() method, like it never even executes. I just want certificate authentication to run with my defined logic in addition to whatever Kestrel, IIS Express, or IIS does.

Can you identify where the problem is? You can add a breakpoint to confirm whether the OnCertificateValidated event is triggered in the AddCertificate method. If the event is not triggered, there may be an issue with the authentication middleware configuration. Then, add logging or a breakpoint in the IsValidClientCertificate method to see if that method is called, which can help determine whether the issue lies in the configuration or the implementation. And you should ensure that your site's SSL settings are correctly configured to accept client certificates.

Nothing is ever executed. The ServiceCollectionExtension methods run and setup everything, but the IsValidClientCertificate method never executes. The AuthenticationService is never instantiated. The browser does not even prompt me for a certificate to start any of the process or for any part of the process to be successful if it did execute. There's no certificate.

So, this morning, I copied over a new launchSettings.json file, and it started prompting me for a certificate. The IsValidClientCertificate method now fires and fails if I select a certificate that is not in my configuration file. However, Context.Fail("Fail reason..."); does not stop the swagger UI from loading for the API. It still loads despite the results of the custom validation.

I want to be as precise as possible, so I need to reiterate that the IsValidClientCertificate method does run, but when it returns context.Fail("Fail Reason"), the swagger UI still displays. When the API is called by a web application, then it still executes the controller method even if the certificate failed my custom validation.

I believe this may be an issue in .NET itself. context.Fail just does not do anything. How can I fail the authentication if not using context.Fail?
